# Number of different wavelengths in the visible spectrum reaching Earth

Tags: visible-light, photons, wavelength

I recognize the visible wavelengths of light extend from approximately 400 - 700 nm.  But how many different wavelengths exist in that range?  300 ?   30,000 ?  (400.01 - 699.99)

If it's completely continuous, then how can photons be so easily absorbed, as they need to match an electron potential fairly precisely to be absorbed?

(I did a naive calculation some time ago, and came up with a wavelength about every 1.5 nm, but I don't know if that is correct.)

Comment: You are assuming that photons are only absorbed by kicking an electron to a higher energy level. But they can be absorbed by many other processes too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: spectrum of sun]

[As you can see](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunlight) the spectrum at the top of the atmosphere is continuous, with some saw tooth excesses, but still continuous.

The absorption does create a saw tooth pattern, even so there is continuity.

To dispel doubts [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fraunhofer_lines) is the sun spectrum showing continuity  and absorption spectra

[image: absorptions spectrum]

> Solar spectrum with Fraunhofer lines as it appears visually.

The first figure has been done registering intensities at each wavelength.

You ask:

> how can photons be so easily absorbed, as they need to match an electron potential fairly precisely to be absorbed

Photons are absorbed when they impinge on atoms with matching energies, and the others are not. Absorption is not the only interaction that photons can have. They can scatter off electrons and lose some energy, [Compton Scattering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compton_scattering), or whole atoms [Raman scattering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raman_scattering) . These do not have precise energy levels.

Comment: I believe the sun spectrum is not related to the question. The question was probably about a potential "discrete" character of the wavelength itself, meaning that there could be forbidden and allowed wavelengths, maybe regularly spaced.

Comment: @fffred The spectrum is the experimental evidence that it is continuous.

Comment: I don't see how a chart indicates the spectrum is continuous, though that might be so.

Comment: I agree with @Jiminion. The spectrum data is discrete anyway, because of the limited resolution of the detector. There might be a fundamental limit to the resolution of wavelengths, or not, but we cannot infer that from the presented data.

Comment: @fffred  please  see my edit

Comment: @Jiminion please see my edit

Comment: @fffred and Jiminion The spectrum is continuous. Consider redshifting and blueshifting. If I have a certain wavelength of a photon, I can redshift or blueshift that wavelength along a continuous spectrum simply by changing my velocity, or through cosmological, or gravitational shifting. The only way to discretize the spectrum is to discretize velocity and position as well. Otherwise, you could easily red/blue shift the wavelength to something not in the determined spectrum

Comment: as for the spectrum we measure from the Sun, it is discrete only because we'd need to measure an infinite number of photons to make it truly continuous

Comment: Who says velocity and position aren't discrete?

Comment: @JimdalftheGrey  the spectrum from the diffraction grating shows much smaller wavelength differences than the width of the absorption lines. Within our measurement system it is continuous.

Comment: @anna, I understand your point about wavelengths shifts, and you are right about that; but showing the sun's spectrum is not at all related to this. No spectrometer has ever, or ever will have an infinitely small resolution, so it is not possible to deduce that the spectrum is continuous from available data. The only option is to say that all established theories assume a continuous spectrum.

Comment: @annav I agree. I just thought I'd head off that argument before it gained any momentum

Comment: So the energy of a particular photon of light at a particular wavelength is always the same, but the wavelengths can very by tiny amounts, so there is therefore a wide spectrum of energies available in photons?  And various absorption methods can accommodate these ranges of energies?

Comment: @Jiminion more or less, if by absorption methods you include loss of energies by compton and raman scatterings that reduce the photon energy. Correspondingly generation of photons happens by atomic transitions of electrons (discrete spectra)  and electrons accelerated in various electric and magnetic fields ( acceleration generates radiation), the latter are continuous spectra.

Answer (score 2):

To my knowledge, there is no discretization of the light wavelength (they form a continuous spectrum).

On the other hand, there exists no infinitely narrow absorption "potential". I mean that all transitions of electrons that may correspond to a photon absorption have a finite width. Consequently, the photons have a non-zero probability to get absorbed.

Moreover, many materials do not have narrow energy transitions. For example, metals have free electrons (not bound to an atom, i.e. not subject to atomic transitions) that may absorb many different photon energies. Other materials absorb light through other processes, such as changes in the vibrations of molecules, or in their rotations, etc. These processes show similar transitions to atomic transitions, but these may have much wider wavelength acceptance.

(Another thing to consider: photons do not have a precisely defined wavelength due to Heisenberg uncertainty principle)